# SQL Server connection parameter for encoding "iso 8559-1"

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, connection-string, collation, iso-8859-1

I have an "iso 8559-1" encoded string, that I want to persist in SQL Server. But my query for insertion results in different string getting into database.

For MySql, I have made it work by :

1. Changing the characterset of column  to latin1
2. setting characterEncoding=ISO-8859-1 in connection properties for jdbc url.

I have tried changing the collation type of column/table to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS, but that didnot serve the purpose.

Then I tried to change the connection property of connection to SQL Server, but not able to find what connection parameter would work in SQL Server.

Does anyone know what settings are required for SQL Server?

Comment: You cannot define a string encoding in the SQL Server connection string.... you need to define the **collation** of your columns when you create the table

Comment: @marc_s: I have defined column collation successfully for SQL Server. For specifying string encoding :
MySql : characterEncoding=ISO-8859-1 
MSSQL: sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false 
In official documentation this parameter is required to be false. On trying this it was, however, not giving me desired result.